# VBA Form - Vlookup cell and assign value to that cell

Tags: vba, excel

Encountering an issue in a VBA regarding vlookup function.

I have 2 comboboxes and 6 Textboxs for user input.

I want to use a vlookup (or index,Match(),Match()) to look up a cell in a data table and assign the values from the textboxes to these cells.

When I run the code for what I believe should work, it is returning object errors.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim MonthlyTable As Range
Set MonthlyTable = Sheets("DATA Monthly").Range("A6:AE400")
Dim ColumnRef As Range
Set ColumnRef = Sheets("Drivers").Range("N11")

' Assign CB2 value to M11 cell reference so it can be converted to a column ref in N11.
Sheets("Drivers").Range("M11").Value = ComboBox2.Value

Dim CB1Value As String
CB1Value = "Joiners" & ComboBox1.Value
Dim CB2Value As String
CB2Value = ComboBox2.Value

MsgBox CB1Value & " " & CB2Value

Dim tb1value As Range
tb1value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CB1Value, MonthlyTable, ColumnRef, False)
tb1value.Value = TextBox1.Value

Unload Me
End Sub
```

I am at a loss for what to do here as I feel like it should be this simple!

Thanks in advance.

Edit. Further digging indicates that you cannot select a cell you are vlookup'ing as this commands only returns a value it does not actually select the cell for my intents and purposes.

Comment: You're missing the `Set` keyword: `Set MonthlyTable = ...`

Comment: Even with the set commands in place it returns the exact same error.

Comment: Your late digging is right. You cannot assign a Range to result of VLookUp. You may want to use `Range.Find()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not really clear to me you actual aim, but just following up your *desire* as stated by:

> I want to use a vlookup (or index,Match(),Match()) to look up a cell
>   in a data table and assign the values from the textboxes to these
>   cells

you may want to adopt the following technique:

```
Dim tb1value As Variant '<--| a variant can be assigned the result of Application.Match method and store an error to be properly cheeked for 
tb1value = Application.Match(CB1Value, MonthlyTable.Column(1), 0) '<--| try finding an exact match for 'CB1Value' in the first column of your data range 
If Not IsError(tblvalue) Then MonthlyTable(tb1value, columnRef.Value).Value = TextBox1.Value '<--| if successful then write 'TextBox1' value in data range cell in the same row of the found match and with `columnRef` range value as its column index
```

Comment: I was sure you could do it in 1 line ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado, while still to be verified I actually made it, it took me three lines...

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses worksheet functions to manipulate data, VBA has different tools, and when you find yourself setting cell values on a sheet via VBA so that some worksheet function can refer to them it is time to look for a true VBA solution. I suggest the following which, by the way, you might consider running on the Change event of Cbx2 instead of a command button.

```
Private Sub Solution_Click()
    ' 24 Mar 2017

    Dim MonthlyTable As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Lookup As String
    Dim Done As Boolean

    Set MonthlyTable = Sheets("DATA Monthly").Range("A2:AE400")
    ' take the lookup value from Cbx1
    Lookup = ComboBox1.Value

    Set Rng = MonthlyTable.Find(Lookup)    
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Chr(34) & Lookup & """ wasn't found.", vbInformation, "Invalid search"
    Else
        With ComboBox2
            If .ListIndex < 0 Then
                MsgBox "Please select a data type.", vbExclamation, "Missing specification"
            Else
                TextBox1.Value = MonthlyTable.Cells(Rng.Row, .ListIndex + 1)
                Done = True
            End If
        End With
    End If

    If Done Then Unload Me
End Sub
```

There are two points that need explanation. First, the form doesn't close after a rejected entry. You would have to add a Cancel button to avoid an unwanted loop where the user can't leave the form until he enters something correct. Note that `Done` is set to True only when the search criterion was found And a value was returned, and the form isn't closed until `Done = True`.

Second, observe the use of the ListIndex property of Cbx2. All the items in that Cbx's dropdown are numbered from 0 and up. The ListIndex property tells which item was selected. It is -1 when no selection was made. If you list the captions of your worksheet columns in the dropdown (you might do this automatically when you initialise the form) there will be a direct relationship between the caption selected by the user (such as "Joiners") and the ListIndex. The first column of MonthlyTable will have the ListIndex 0. So you can convert the ListIndex into a column of MonthlyTable by adding 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use "find" in excell vba to select a cell instead of using vlookup or other methods.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).